# find merged user suggestion using list comprehension

Tags: python

i need to show merged suggestion

**input format**

```
m = {'user1': {'c1': ['p1', 'e1'],
  'c2': ['p2', 'e2'],
  'c3': ['p2', 'e3'],
  'c4': ['e3', 'p4'],
  'c5': ['e2', 'p5'],
  'c6': ['p3', 'e4', 'p6'],
  'c7': ['e4'],
  'c8': ['p6', 'e5']}}
```

**i need to show  merged suggestion for this user on the basis of p1,p2... and e1,e2 ... on dict values , there could be multiple users**

**output format**

```
user1_merge_suggestions : [ [c1], [c2, c3, c4, c5], [c6, c7, c8] ]
```

explanation

for key c1 its values are p1 and e1 which is not present in any other key-value pair so c1 is alone appended to the list , for key c2 value p2 is found in key c3 value and value of key c3 which is e3 found in c4 and value of key c5 which is p2 is found in key c2 so they are related  so [c2,c3,c4,c5] and so on

Comment: What's the logic behind desired output? And what have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: logic is for user1 if any value for key c1 matches with any value of any other key ,it should show in the merge suggestion output

Comment: I'm now seeing the logic thanks to your comment, but what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i am also trying will post my buggy code in few minutes

Comment: "Few minutes". :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# first aggregate all users
merged = defaultdict(set)
for u in m:
    for k,v in m[u].iteritems():
        merged[(k,)].update(set(v))

# then merged keys as required as long as possible
cont = True
while cont:
    cont = False
    keys = merged.keys()
    L = len(keys)
    for i in range(L):
        ki = keys[i]
        for j in range(i+1,L):
            kj = keys[j]
            if merged[ki] & merged[kj]:
                merged[ki+kj] = merged[ki].union(merged[kj])
                del merged[ki]
                del merged[kj]
                cont = True

# finally remove remaining artifacts  
merged = [k for k,v in merged.iteritems() if v]
```

Comment: i think we are getting list of tuples ,above output is list of lists

Comment: got it btw thanx a lot